# Json parsing on cli using jq

Tags: json, bash, command-line, jq

Let's say I have the below json object:

```
{
  "d": {
    "e": {
      "bar": 2
    }
  },
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "foo": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the value foo without typing `'.a.b.c.foo'`

I realize I can do...
`echo '{ "a":{"b":{"c":{ "foo":1}}},"d":{"e":{"bar":2}}}' | jq '.[][][].foo'` but is there a recursive wild in jq? like **? I know for sure jq doesn't support *, is there a way to have jq support jsonpath?
Or maybe even just another cli tool that does support json path?

Comment: What about a recursive for in loop? Iterating over all the properties on each object in your hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jq 1.4 you could do this:

```
$ jq '..|.foo?' file.json
```

If you're stuck with 1.3 you could use

```
$ jq 'recurse(if type == "array" or type == "object" then .[] else empty end) | if type == "object" then . else empty end | .foo' file.json
```

which is a bit of a mouthful...  That's why 1.4 has `..`, which recurses down through all iterables in `.`, and the `?` operator, which doesn't bother indexing that which can't be.

Comment: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/319 more info can be found here. essentially: `jq '..|.foo? | select(type != "null")'`